# Is it possible that $a^2+b^2+c^2 = d^2+e^2+f^2$?

Tags: number-theory

> Let $a,b,c$ be nonnegative integers such that $a \leq b \leq c, 2b \neq a+c$ and $\frac{a+b+c}{3}$ is an integer. Is it possible to find three nonnegative integers $d,e,$ and $f$ such that $d \leq e \leq f, f \neq c,$ and such that $a^2+b^2+c^2 = d^2+e^2+f^2$?

I have tried it for examples such as $a=1,b=2,c=6$, we have $1^2+2^2+6^2 = 41 = 0^2+4^2+5^2$ and it always seems to work. I am wondering how to use the fact that $\frac{a+b+c}{3}$ is an integer and wondering if it may be related to the AM-GM inequality. How should I use this information to solve the question?

Comment: If $a=1, b=2, c=9$, then what is $d, e, f$?

Comment: @See-Woo Lee We can choose $1,6,7$.

Comment: Maybe this will help?  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1243182_one_symmetric_equation

Comment: If I haven't made any errors, I've been able to rule out counterexamples with $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \le 10^5$.

Comment: Every number that is not of the form $4^m(8k+7)$ can be represented as a sum of three squares, and we also have asymptotics for the number of representations due to Hardy's earlier works, so, in general, we expect plenty of solutions. The arithmetical constraints $a+b+c\in 3\mathbb{Z}$ and $2b\neq a+c$ are not that strong to radically change the previous behaviour (for short: they are quite irrelevant).

Comment: $$3^2+4^2+12^2=0^2+0^2+13^2$$ comes from "interlacing" the Pythagorean triples $(3,4,5)$ and $(5,12,13)$ and leads to $$9^2+12^2+36^2=0^2+0^2+39^2$$. You may construct as many examples as you want by this way.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: got it. 
The matrix $$ \frac{1}{3} \left( \begin{array}{rrr} 2 & 2 & -1 \\ 2 & -1 & 2 \\ -1 & 2 & 2 \end{array} \right) $$ is orthogonal.
 Given any such $a,b,c$ we can make a successful new triple 
$$ \frac{|2a+2b-c|}{3}, \; \; \frac{2a - b + 2 c}{3}, \; \; \frac{-a + 2b + 2c}{3}  $$

We do need to show that the absolute value is not the largest item;
$$  a + 4b + c > 0, $$
$$ a - 2 b - 2 c = a - 2 b - 2 c, $$
$$  2a + 2b - c > a - 2b-2c = -(-a+2b+2c) $$
$$  |2a + 2b - c| < (-a+2b+2c). $$
The other ingredient: since $2b \neq a+c, $ we find $-a+2b+2c \neq 3c.$ That is, the largest item is different from the original $c.$

For the interested, the reference for this mapping is [PALL Automorphs 1940](http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Pall_Automorphs_1940.pdf)

$$  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc   \bigcirc   $$

ORIGINAL: As long as we stick to numbers not divisible by $4,$ we expect that any restriction of the type stated is overwhelmed by the increasing count of representations as the sum of three squares. Anyway, not divisible by four, the numbers below seem to be all of those for which the largest, $c,$ is fixed in $n = a^2 + b^2 + c^2.$ Just so you know, among numbers not divisible by $4,$ the only numbers ***not*** expressible as the sum of three squares are those $m \equiv 7 \pmod 8.$ Note how, for each triple, either the sum is nonzero mod 3, or $2b = a+c.$ I probably know ways to deal with numbers off this list, nothing comes to mind yet.

Here is one of my articles [in this area](http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Kap_Jagy_Schiemann_1997.pdf)

```
1          0      0      1  mod three 1
2          0      1      1  mod three 2
3          1      1      1  mod three 0 two b 
5          0      1      2  mod three 0 two b 
6          1      1      2  mod three 1
10          0      1      3  mod three 1
11          1      1      3  mod three 2
13          0      2      3  mod three 2
14          1      2      3  mod three 0 two b 
19          1      3      3  mod three 1
21          1      2      4  mod three 1
22          2      3      3  mod three 2
30          1      2      5  mod three 2
35          1      3      5  mod three 0 two b 
37          0      1      6  mod three 1
42          1      4      5  mod three 1
43          3      3      5  mod three 2
46          1      3      6  mod three 1
58          0      3      7  mod three 1
61          3      4      6  mod three 1          0      5      6  mod three 2
67          3      3      7  mod three 1
70          3      5      6  mod three 2
78          2      5      7  mod three 2
91          1      3      9  mod three 1
93          2      5      8  mod three 0 two b 
106          3      4      9  mod three 1          0      5      9  mod three 2
115          3      5      9  mod three 2
133          4      6      9  mod three 1
142          5      6      9  mod three 2
163          1      9      9  mod three 1
165          4      7     10  mod three 0 two b           1      8     10  mod three 1
190          3      9     10  mod three 1
235          1      3     15  mod three 1
253          3     10     12  mod three 1
310          6      7     15  mod three 1          2      9     15  mod three 2
355          7      9     15  mod three 1          3     11     15  mod three 2
403          3     13     15  mod three 1
427          9     11     15  mod three 2
795          7     11     25  mod three 1          1     13     25  mod three 0 two b 
883          9     19     21  mod three 1          1     21     21  mod three 1
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Answer (score 3):

Short answer (explained in the comments above):

$$ (4x)^2+(4x^2-1)^2    =  (4x^2+1)^2 $$
can be "interlaced" with
$$ (4x^2+1)^2 + (8x^4+4x^2)^2 =  (8x^4+4x^2+1)^2 $$
to get:
$$ (4x)^2 + (4x^2-1)^2 + (8x^4+4x^2)^2 = 0^2 + 0^2 + (8x^4+4x^2+1)^2 $$
or:

> $$ (12x)^2 + (12x^2-3)^2 + (24x^4+12x^2)^2 = 0^2 + 0^2 + (24x^4+12x^2+3)^2 $$

i.e. an infinite number of solutions.

Easier approach: we may take three positive integers $N=4u+1$, $M=4v-1$, $ N+M=4(u+v)$
and write them as a difference of two squares,

$$N=a^2-d^2,\quad  M=b^2-e^2,\quad  N+M=f^2-c^2.$$
We get $a^2+b^2+c^2=d^2+e^2+f^2$ with $f> c$ and we just need very few work to ensure the other constraints.